# using gem watir : is there a way to get the pid of an opened browser (for killing that particular process)?

Tags: ruby, watir

I have been searching quite long and I didn't find any **elegant** solution I mean using some watir methods...

I am trying this (not elegant). the list "ante" is the list of pids concerning watir chrome browsers already opened and before opening the new browser. 
The list "post" is the list of all pids after creating the new browser.
the list "tobekilled" is the difference of the 2.

Here is my code. Waiting for some lag to be tested :)

```
def brow_gotosafe  url

  begin
    # liste_ante des pid chrome
    # liste des process type chromedriver n chromwebdriver
    # listedes pids : ante
    ante = []
    system('ps -Af | grep chromedriver > ../assets/chrdrv_ante.txt')
    system('ps -Af | grep "webdriver --use-mock" > ../assets/chromwebdriver_ante.txt')

    File.readlines("../assets/chrdrv_ante.txt").each do |line|
      ante << line.split(" ")[1].to_i
    end
    File.readlines("../assets/chromwebdriver_ante.txt").each do |line|
      ante << line.split(" ")[1].to_i
    end
    pp ante
    # on cree le browser et on point sur l url
    br = Watir::Browser.new
    br.goto url
  rescue => e
    puts e.class
    puts e.message
    puts e.backtrace.inspect

    # on ferme le browser br
    begin
      Timeout::timeout(5) { br.close }
    rescue Timeout::Error
      # on va fermer le br via le systeme
      # creation nouvelle liste : post
      post = []
      system('ps -Af | grep chromedriver > ../assets/chrdrv_post.txt')
      system('ps -Af | grep "webdriver --use-mock" > ../assets/chromwebdriver_post.txt')

      File.readlines("../assets/chrdrv_post.txt").each do |line|
        post << line.split(" ")[1].to_i
      end
      File.readlines("../assets/chromwebdriver_post.txt").each do |line|
        post << line.split(" ")[1].to_i
      end
      pp post

      # liste_tobekilled = liste_post - liste_ante
      tobekilled = []
      post.each do |p|
        if !ante.include?(p)
          tobekilled << p
        end
      end
      pp tobekilled

      # killing the pids tbk
      tobekilled.each do |tbk|
        system("kill #{tbk}")
      end

    end
  retry # on va au debut du begin
  end
  # c'est le resultat de la methode le browser br pointant sur url
  br
end
```

The fact is I am using watir gem. Not watir-classic nor watir-webdriver.
Thx for your help.

Comment: What is the non-elegant solution(s) you found?

Comment: I am writing a method comparing the list of the pids of chrome after and before launching the watir browser. And destroying them.

Answer (score 2):

Did a quick test and this always kills the browser unless for some reason you want parent process to stay alive.

```
def brow_gotosafe url
require 'timeout'
require 'watir'

    begin          
      br = Watir::Browser.new    
      br.goto url  
      pid = $$
      puts "this is pid: #{pid}"  
      puts "lets test script execution fail: "
      asdasdasd #this will fail execution         
    rescue => e
      puts "browser exists: #{br.exists?}"  
      puts "error class: #{e.class}"  
      puts "error message: #{e.message}"  
      puts "error inspect: #{e.backtrace.inspect}"  

      begin
          puts "lets test failin to close the browser within timeout: "    
          Timeout::timeout(5) {           
            #br.close
            sleep 10
           }
      rescue Timeout::Error
        puts "Timeout error happened, browser still exists: #{br.exists?}"  
        puts "Killing browser by killing pid #{pid.to_s}"  
        system("kill #{pid}") 
      end    
    ensure
      #consider putting it here as well
      begin
        Timeout::timeout(5) { br.close }
      rescue Timeout::Error
        system("kill #{pid}") 
      end  
    end
end

brow_gotosafe "www.google.com"
```

This way you don't need to grep processes into files then read files into arrays and compare arrays before and after execution.

Because every execution will *cleanup* its opened browser if it doesn't close gracefully within timeout (by killing its parent)

Hope it works for you.

edit: parent needs to stay alive

After digging through browser instance I only managed to find chromedriver/geckodriver pid, but since browser instance is firstborn child of chromedriver/geckodriver, you can easily fetch browser pid with *ps*

```
def brow_gotosafe url
  require 'timeout'
  require 'watir'  

  begin          
    br = Watir::Browser.new    
    br.goto url      
    driver_pid = br.driver.instance_variable_get(:@service).instance_variable_get(:@process).instance_variable_get(:@pid)
    puts "this is driver_pid pid: #{driver_pid}" 
    browser_pid =  `ps --ppid #{driver_pid} | awk '{print $1}'| sed "1 d"`
    puts "this is browser pid: #{browser_pid}"  
    puts "lets test script execution fail: "
    asdasdasd #this will fail execution         
  rescue => e
    puts "browser exists: #{br.exists?}"  
    puts "error class: #{e.class}"  
    puts "error message: #{e.message}"  
    puts "error inspect: #{e.backtrace.inspect}"  

    begin
        puts "lets test failin to close the browser within timeout: "    
        Timeout::timeout(5) {           
          #br.close
          sleep 10
         }
    rescue Timeout::Error
      puts "Timeout error happened"  
      puts "Killing browser by killing browser pid #{browser_pid}"  
      system("kill -9 #{browser_pid}")    
      sleep 20 #here check if browser is really killed
      puts "if youre seeing this then main process exists after killing 
      browser"  
    end  
  end
end

brow_gotosafe "www.google.com"
```

Comment: not bad :) however in my case I want parent to stay alive !